# Project.AddInterface seemingly never available

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio I have mapped Project.AddInterface to a keyboard shortcut, and when I press it, the status bar updates with this:

> The key combination (Alt A, V) is bound to command (Add Interface...) which is not currently available.

It is seemingly never available however - if the context is in the code editor, solution explorer, or anything else sensible I've tried it doesn't work, with the same result as above every time.

A solution involving installing an extension that is free and doesn't require administrator privileges would work for me. I've got some limitations on those points.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here? This happens in VS2013 Premium and VS2015 Community.

Comment: While I set up the binding in mine, it doesn't give the error, it also doesn't do anything at all. I'd suggest creating a snippet if you can't get this to work.

Comment: Interesting to note that it doesn't do anything when it "works". Thanks for that info.

Comment: Probably dates back to the previous century, probably in the C++ IDE.  Compare to Project.AddClass, which is implemented but doesn't add a class.

Comment: I'm not having the issue with Project.AddClass, it opens the dialog fine. One could then select the interface item, but what's the point in being able to assign the key chord if it doesn't open the dialog with interface template selected. I might as well use my mouse.